# UI-Scaling issue [KDE] [Nvidia-driver-510]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde, display-resolution

I'm having issues with my Display and Graphics resolution. I'm running a Kubuntu 20.04 LTS System with an AMD Rhyzen 3700X and a GTX 1080. The system drives two monitors a ultrawide 2560*1080 and a 3840*2160 Display.

In Windows I had the 4k Display set to 125% Scaling and the Ultrawide set to 100%. It is not particularly comfortable but it works, using a technique which involves draging the cursor always through the "bottom" of the monitor.

Now in Linux, I wanted the same thing. I firstly tried a per monitor scaling but this didn't seem to work, xrandr didn't really respond to what I was doing. So I setteled on using only the system with the scaling for both monitors set to 125%.

Since I intend on using Davinci Resolve in the Future, I installed the NVIDIA drivers. This resulted in a catastrophic graphics scaling (ref. Pictures).

Using NVIDIA, every window that comes with the Desktop environment of Kubuntu (I believe it's KDE or Plasma?) is scale to a ridiculous level. The kicker. If I set the resolution to 100% it doesn't improve.

Tinkering around with xrandr again, it seemed that the scaling was inverse proportional, i.e. where I'd usually set the scale to 125% I had to set it to 80% to get it to scale properly. This resulted in the 4k monitor rendering just fine but the Ultrawide having part of it turning off / becoming black when I tried to scale with xrandr. That' why I quickly scratched this idea.

I then went on to try different scalings from 100% to 200% and different renderers (xrender, opengl2.0 and opengl3.1). The interesting part was, that the font resolution changed but not the windows them self, the padding remained the same and the absolute font size in pixels as well. The login animation sometimes changed. I didn't really understand what exactly was affected by what.

The peculiar part about this is, that everything **not** rendered by the KDE (or plasma?) is remaining on it's native resolution. This being for exapmle Spotify rendered by X11 I believe and Golang with some java framework used to render it. It was affected when the nouveau display driver was installed but now wasn't any more.

I'd really like to have it run just like on Windows, with the Nvidia driver and the ui on a normal scale. Preferably with settings that actually do what you'd expect them to and not decrese the resolution and what not.

If somebody knows how to fix this issue or has a deeper understanding of how the desktop is rendered and where I need to tune some parameters in the rendering pipeline I'd greatly appreciate a response.

Thanks in Advance

A.S.

[To the Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA1pM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is surprisingly simple and surprisingly unsatisfying.

The solution was to uninstall the drivers, wait until yesterday (8.5.2022) in reference to the post date and reinstall the drivers.

I also figured out that I had to reconfigure the Desktop (Create a new Pane in KDE because it went missing and then reduce the size so it's not as ugly). Then I went into the settings and the scaling slider actually affected the scaling of everything.

And that seems to be it for solving the issues.

I would really like to offer an explanation but I cant.